# Why setup complete window is not shown during install SQL Server 2014 on Windows 10?

Tags: sql-server

When I try to install SQL Server 2014 on Windows 10, the setup complete window is not shown. Please help me how do I fix this problem?

[image: install]

Comment: Because it's still running?

Comment: it takes 4 or 5 hours but still not showing setup complete window.

Comment: Press Alt+Tab several times to make sure there are no hidden windows.

Comment: previously when i installed sql 2014, it does not take long time to complete setup.so i am worried about this problem.so please help me.